# how to generate automatically id number based on the drop down selection with last id from the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form in which there is a field called index. What I want to do is to generate a index number automatically as follows.

```
ex: option1_01 , option2_01 , option1_02 .. etc
```

`option1` comes based on the drop down selection. and `_01` comes from the database using the last id number of table `option1`.

here is my **form.php**

```
 <body>
<form id="" method="post" action="send.php">
<select name="name" id="name">
    <option value="">please select</option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select><br>
<label for="index">Index</label>
    <input type="text" id="index" name="index" readonly="readonly" value=""/><br>
<label for="fname">fname</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname"/><br>
<label for="lname">lname</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname"/><br>
<label for="age">age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age"/>
<button name="submit">sumit</button>
</form> 
</body>
```

Also I have two tables to insert data. when we select `option1`, rest of details should go into `option1` table.

**db.php**

```
<?php
           $servername = "localhost";
           $username = "root";
           $password = "";
           $db = "testing01";

 // Create connection
           $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            echo "Connected successfully <br/>";
?>
```

here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

$("#name option").filter(function() {    
      return $(this).val() == $("#index").val(); 
    }).attr('selected', true);  

var index1 = $("#index").val();

$("#name").on("change", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'table.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{index1:index2},
        success:function(){
         $("#index").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        }
    });
});
});
```

**table.php**

```
<?php   
             $index2 = $_POST['index2'];
             include("db.php");

                $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM ".$index2." ";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $get = mysqli_fetch_array($res); 
                $next_id = $get['MAX(id)'] + 1;

        }
?>
```

**send.php**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $option=$_POST['name'];
    $index=$_POST['index'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];


    include('db.php');

    if($option=="option1"){
        $result1=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO option1(options,fname,lname,age) VALUES('$option','$fname','$lname','$age');");
      if($result1){
      echo "data inserted to option1 table";
    }
    }

    if($option=="option2"){
      $result2=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO option2(options,fname,lname,age) VALUES('$option','$fname','$lname','$age');");
      if($result2){
      echo "data inserted to option2 table";
    }
    }
    }
?>
```

I think I have the problem in $ajax code snippet. it pass `index2` varible into `table.php`. but i am unable to get back `$next_id` because I am new to jquery.
anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved myself

my jquery code snippet should be changed as here

```
$(document).ready(function(){                                       
        $('#name').on('change', function() {
           $('#index').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'));

           var index1 = $('#index').val();

        $.ajax({
             url:'table.php',
             type:'post',
             data:{index1:index2},
             dataType:'json',
             success:function(data){

                var next_id = data;
                $("#index").val(index1 + "_" + next_id);
                //alert('success');
                 }
           });


        });
     });
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM ".$index2." ";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $get = mysqli_fetch_array($res); 
                $next_id = $get['max_id'] + 1;
                echo $next_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use alias `MAX(id) as maxId` in query to get record.

**Table.php**

```
<?php   
             $index2 = $_POST['index2'];
             include("db.php");

                $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) as maxId FROM ".$index2." ";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $get = mysqli_fetch_array($res); 
                $next_id = $get['maxId'] + 1;

        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your ajax script has no result.

try this

```
$("#name").on("change", function() {
$.ajax({
    url:'table.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{index1:index2},
    success:function(result){

     //result = $next_id from your table.php script...

     $("#index").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    }
 });
});
```

and in your insert script:

```
            ......
            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $get = mysqli_fetch_array($res); 
            $next_id = $get['maxId'] + 1;
            echo $next_id;
```

$next_id will be passed back to the ajax script in the result variable. (you can actually call this whatever you want...)

you can then do what you want with result as it will = $next_id

EDIT:

Also, I dont see a definition for index2 in your jquery code.

Comment: yeh @bart2puck , what you mentioned is the thing actually I want.

Comment: So are u having trouble getting it in the MySQL call or applying it to the option field in your Ajax call?

Comment: I see      var index1 = $("#index").val();       but dont see var index2 in the jquery snippet..

Comment: data:{index1:index2},

Comment: That basically says the value of index1 = index2.   the value of index2 is not defined. I get "index2 is not defined(…)" if i run your code.